# How to get values from a template with slot and slot-scope in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I want to get the values when i use slot and slot-scope inside of a data iterator. I am using Vuetify to get the data.

Here is an example:

```
<v-data-iterator :search="search" :loading="loading" content-tag="v-layout" row wrap :items="items" :pagination.sync="pagination">
<v-flex slot="item" slot-scope="props" xs12 sm6 md6 lg3>
<v-card>
 <v-list-tile>
    <v-list-tile-content>Apellido Paterno:</v-list-tile-content>
      <v-list-tile-content class="align-end">{{props.item.volumenActual}}</v-list-tile-content>
 </v-list-tile>
</v-card>
</v-flex>
</v-data-iterator>
```

I am using axios to obtain the data and use `response.data` to pass it to my items[{}] array.

I tried somethig like this in my method of axios but it doesn't work, it shows nothing:
`this.newValue = response.data.volumenActual`.

Before, to get it the value, i used `@click="myMethod(props.item)"` in a button, but now, i dont want a button, because i'm going to interact with the value dynamically in another method like calculate percentage.

Answer (score 0):

If someone helps this, here is my answer:
I only pass the value to create a method like this:

inside from my loop:

```
<p>{{doSomething(props.item.value)}}</p>
```

So, I make a method to manipulate the values

```
 doSomething(value) {
      var something = value / 1000;
      return something + "%";
    },
```